# 数字用キーボードで「完了」ボタンを設けるにはどうすれば良いですか？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

いつもお世話になっております。
表題の件について質問です。

数字用のキーボードは、通常「完了」ボタンはありませんよね？
なので、キーボードを下げる（隠す）場合は、

```
@IBAction func tapScreen(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

を使って、キーボード以外の部分をタップして対応しているものと思っています。

ところが、
あるサイトで数字を入力する際、下記のように「完了」ボタンのついたキーボードを見かけました。
このキーボード、おまけに入力欄の移動を < > を使って行き来ができるスグレモノです。

このキーボードを使うには、どうすれば良いか？
ご存知の型がいらっしゃればお教え下さい。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「完了」だけでしたら、"swift キーボード 完了ボタン"あたりで検索すれば、わかりやすく書いてくれているサイトが多数見つかります。単純に「完了ボタン付きを表す１行追加するだけ」とはいかないので、それらのサイトを参考にある程度やってみて、うまくいかないところが出てきたら、その部分のコード等を質問に追記していただければと思います。「入力欄の移動を < > を使って行き来ができる」については、iOS側にサポートする機能がないのでさらにもうちょっと面倒なことになります。「完了」が確実にできるようになってから、必要性と意欲に合わせて次の課題とされた方が良いのではないかと思います。

Comment: 「完了」と「 < > 」があるということは、WebViewのテキストフィールドでしょうね。WebのテキストフィールドについてはOSが自動的にキーボードの上部にそれらのボタンを追加してくれます。自分のアプリで実現する場合には自分で実装する必要があります。キーボード上部のツールバーはアクセサリビューと言います。ですので「ios キーボード accessoryview」などといった検索語を用いて調べるとよいでしょう。